# Using C# & LINQ how can I find duplicate file names?

Tags: c#, linq

I've spent some time trying to find the answer and I'm close but still stuck.

Imagine you have the following folders and text files..

```
C:\dupfiles
C:\dupfiles\tarts
C:\dupfiles\tarts\moretarts

C:\dupfiles\tarts\lindsay.txt
C:\dupfiles\paris.txt
C:\dupfiles\britney.txt
C:\dupfiles\tarts\moretarts\britney.txt
C:\dupfiles\tarts\moretarts\paris.txt
```

I"m trying to run a LINQ query that displays the duplicates (paris.txt & britney.txt). In SQL you would do this via a group by and a having clause.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String strPath = @"C:\dupfiles";

        var filelist = from file in Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       select file
                       into files
                       select Path.GetFileName(files);

        var duplicateNames = filelist.GroupBy(file => filelist)
                           .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                           .Select(group => group.Key);       

        foreach (var f in duplicateNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I don't fully understand how the code works and the result is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Here is the output...

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]
```

In the example code f is a type of... System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator

I'm missing a piece of the puzzle. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the type of `f`?

Comment: When you debug this, what does `duplicateNames` actually contain.  It doesn't appear to be a list of strings like you think.

Comment: see if this helps you out: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/5457/csharp-code-to-find-duplicates-in-text-file

Comment: duplicateNames is just a query, try adding `.ToList()` after your `Select` to run the query and turn it into a list.

Comment: @mrfreester `foreach` accomplishes the same thing--i.e. execution of the iterator.

Comment: `into files` can be removed, you can `select Path.GetFileName(file)`. You should group by file, not by filelist which is collection.

Comment: @KennethK. thanks for the catch, I just saw the enumerable and didn't look closely at the code. @codingguy3000 you'll have to do a `foreach` over `f` as it stands to get the filenames, but I think you'll still need to group as @Pavel suggests

Comment: I would still use filelist but group by filelist.Substring(filelist.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) so you have both the filename and the full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are fine. If you want to stick with query syntax, then you could have something like this:

```
var duplicateNames = from filePath in Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     group filePath by Path.GetFileName(filePath) into files
                     where files.Count() > 1
                     select files;
```

I'd personally choose to introduce a `let` clause for readability's sake:

```
var duplicateNames = from filePath in Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     let filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                     group filePath by filename into files
                     where files.Count() > 1
                     select files;
```

A `let` is basically a temporary variable that you have access to throughout your query.

You could then print these items out using a nested `foreach` as Joshua Miller demonstrates.

Comment: Awesome answer Kenneth. I'm trying to understand the code. How could I include the file name and the file path in the result set?

Comment: You have both. The group key is the filename; the group itself is each file (including path).

Comment: i.e. Look at [Joshua Miller's `foreach` loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42077718/884561). Same concept.

Answer (score 3):

For some criteria, such as ease of maintanability and speed, LINQ is not necessarily the best answer.

For example, you could have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` which contains the filenames and the paths to the duplicates:

```
static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetDupes2(string baseDir)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> files = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    foreach (string f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var fName = Path.GetFileName(f);
        if (files.ContainsKey(fName))
        {
            files[fName].Add(f);
        }
        else
        {
            files.Add(fName, new List<string> { f });
        }
    }

    return files;

}
```

The keys are the filenames, and the values are lists of the full pathnames of the files. Simply use `files.Where(f => (f.Value.Count > 1))` to get the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

- If you are looking for an answer with query syntax, check out
  [Kenneth K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078994/1542187).
- If you have *a lot* of files to go through and thus need an efficient solution, I would suggest checking
  out [Andrew Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078139/1542187).
- This answer provides a suggestion on printing.

---

This answer will also write the full file paths of all duplicates.

```
var strPath  = @"YourPath";

var dupeFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strPath , "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(fullPath => new
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(fullPath),
        FullPath = fullPath
    })
    .GroupBy(file => file.Name)
    .Where(fileGroup => fileGroup.Count() > 1);

foreach (var dupeGroup in dupeFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dupeGroup.Key);
    foreach (var dupeFile in dupeGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"   {dupeFile.FullPath}");   
    }
}
```

It accomplishes this through the use of an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

As stated above, this will cause the output to display the title of the duplicate file as well as the full paths of all duplicates similar to the example output below.

```
dupe.txt
   C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\Temp\dupe.txt
   C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\Temp\tarts\dupe.txt
dupe2.txt
   C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\Temp\dupe2.txt
   C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\Temp\tarts\dupe2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This code filters file names by `Count` of the groups and selects `Key` which contains the file name.

```
string[] duplicitNames = Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
    .GroupBy (f => f)
    .Where (g => g.Count () > 1)
    .Select (g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

For better understanding the code could be separated into two parts e.g. like this where `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface represents a collection of objects that have a common key. And the `g` is such a grouping. HTH

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> groupedFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
    .GroupBy (f => f);

string[] duplicitNames = groupedFileNames
    .Where (g => g.Count () > 1)
    .Select (g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

*Note:*
Signature of [IGrouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx) looks like this and as you can see it implements `IEnumerable` where the `Count` comes from:

`public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> 
    : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable`.

Comment: Yes this is the answer. One question. I don't understand the .Where (g=> g.Count () > 1). Where does g get the.count method from?

Comment: @codingguy3000 `.GroupBy` creates a list of objects that implement [`IGrouping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx). Since the `.Where` clause is acting upon a list of IGrouping objects, the variable `g` is an IGrouping object itself. Thus, you have access to the method .Count().